# how to hook on a table cell in spss using python?

Tags: python, events, event-handling, spss

I want to write a hopefully short python script that would do things with the contents of a specially formatted text cell of an spss data table.

How can I hook on the event that the user clicked into a data cell? How can I then get its value and do things I want? Does spss have clear-cut interface for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot catch events using the programmability or scripting apis.  The only formatting in the Data Editor comes from variable formats (and column width) except for the special coloring using with missing data imputation.  Tables in the Viewer, of course, have extensive cell formatting capabilities.

Comment: My task is the following: spss allow only concrete types, numbers and strings in the cell. But a friend asked me if we could extend spss so that it would link external files upon a specially formatted cell. Is this doable? What feature of the python binding need I use?